# Quality of discreet data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a table of various types of containers (df_1). I have another table of what they contain (df_2). I would like to asses which rows of df_1 are more likely to be classified as their true type based on whether what they contain is typical for that type of container.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Container' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                          'Type' : ['Box','Bag','Bin','Bag','Bin','Box','Bag','Bin','Bin','Bin']})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Container' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,9],
                          'Item' : ['Ball','Ball','Brain','Ball','Ball','Baloon','Brain','Ball','Ball','Baloon','Brain','Ball','Ball','Baloon','Brain','Ball','Ball','Baloon','Bomb','Ball','Ball','Baloon','Brain','Ball','Ball','Bomb','Bum']})
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach takes account of whether the contents of each container are typical of that type. It gives equal weight to the presence of items that are found in other containers (positive) and to the presence of items not found in other containers (negative). It disregards how frequently an item is found in the other containers. It also disregards whether the contents are typical of another type of container.
I think that this approach would scale up.

```
# List of how typical the contents of each container are given the type of container
x = []

# Join
df_J = df_1 .set_index('Container').join(df_2 .set_index('Container'))
df_J['Container'] = df_J.index
df_J.index = range(len(df_J.index))
df_J ['Thing'] = 1

# Type of each container
Q_B = pd.DataFrame(df_1.Container).set_index('Container')
Q_B['Type'] = df_1.set_index('Container').Type
Di_Q_B = dict(zip(Q_B.index, Q_B.Type))

# Compare each container against all of the other containers
for Container in df_1.Container:

    # Test data: Everything in the container
    Te_C = df_2[df_2['Container'] == Container]
    del Te_C['Container']

    # Everything in all of the other containers
    Tr_C = df_J[df_J['Container'] != Container]

    # Training data: Everything in all of the other containers of that type
    Tr_E = Tr_C[Tr_C['Type'] == Di_Q_B[Container]]

    # Table of how many of each item is in each container
    S_Tr = pd.pivot_table(Tr_E, values='Thing', index=Tr_E.Container, columns='Item', aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)

    # Table of whether each item is in each container
    Q_Tr = S_Tr.apply(np.sign)

    # Table of how many containers in the training data contain each item
    X_Tr = Q_Tr.sum(axis=0)
    Y_Tr = pd.DataFrame(X_Tr)

    # Table of whether any containers in the training data contain each item
    Z_Tr = Y_Tr.apply(np .sign)

    # List of which items are in the training data
    Train = list(Z_Tr.index)

    # Identify which of the items in the container are typical
    Te_C['Typical'] = Te_C['Item'].map(lambda a: a in Train)

    # Count how many typical items are in the container
    u = Te_C['Typical'].sum()

    # Count how many atypical items items are in the container
    v = len(Te_C.index) - u

    # Gauge how typical the contents of the container are (giving equal weight to typical and atypical items)
    w = u - v
    x.append(w)

# How typical the contents of each container are given the type of container
df_1['Pa_Ty'] = x
```

This gives the result df_1:

[image]

Comment: It says "SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  v = len(Te_C) - u = Te_C['Typical'].sum()" Should I change it?